# Dealing with child collections updates in Web API

Tags: c#, rest, api-design, web-api, asp.net-core

Let's take some classic enterprise example: `Order` and `OrderItem`

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Now, what's the most reasonable way to update the order's items using `PUT` or `PATCH` (JSON Patch) ?

Should I `PUT api/orders/{id}` with a new collection (with removed, added or updated items) or handle it differently someway? Like instead of returning a serialized collection of items, return list or links for each item like: `api/orders/{id}/items/{id}`. So it would be more *HATEOAS* like and *REST* like...

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Link> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then if I wanted to update or remove some item from the order I would use those links, but the downside of this is that client-side implementation will not be that straightforward.

The other solution I can think of is returning ids of items like:

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Guid> Items { get; set; }
}
```

but it doesn't look too nice for me, so what is more or less industry standard for dealing with this?

- Returning embedded items
- Returning item URLs
- Returning item ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Order has the OrderItems attached then you should just update Order and not provide api methods for OrderItems.

so

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

api/orders/UpdateOrder {"Id" : "guid" "Items" : [{...},{...}] }
api/orders/GetOrderById
```

If OrderItem just has an OrderId and Order doesn't contain a list of them, then you should have api methods for OrderItems

so.

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid OrderId { get; set; }
}

api/orders/UpdateOrder {"Id" : "guid"}
api/orders/GetOrderById

api/orders/UpdateOrderItem {...}
api/orders/GetOrderItemsByOrderId
api/orders/DeleteOrderItem
```

*avoiding HTTP verbs for clarity

At first glance the complex object/aggregate/first approach seems far superior. But as you object starts getting larger, and you are only needing some of the child objects for certain operations, the second approach can become more efficient.

For example, you can imagine that I might want to know and do lots of things about/with a Company object without loading the List of all its Employees past and present every time.

Comment: An order cannot exist without the items.

Comment: Then, looks wise to modify the "aggregated" as a whole (order), instead of its details separately. For the mere reason, that "Order" probably should comply with certain business rules where the coherence of its details matters. In other words, `PUT /oerder/{id}` and send back to the server the final state of the order. then allow the server to validate its consistency previous to any update in the datastore

Comment: Additionally, ` return list or links for each item like: api/orders/{id}/items/{id}. So it would be more HATEOAS like and REST like...` there's something named `embedded links` that mix both concepts "representation + link". Basically what pages of paginated resources are. Anyways, still prevails what I have suggested in the above comment. Allow users to discover OrderItems, but don't allow them to modify it aside from the Order since Order is who looks after of its data consistency. As a whole not as the sum of the elements.

Comment: hmm I would never recommend HATEOAS, let me edit and add more detail, see if you still think its wise

Comment: @Konrad what happens if i remove all the items from an order? or create an order but haven't added any items yet?

Comment: @Ewan good point, if you haven't added any items to the order the order cannot be created. If you have removed all the items from an order it shouldn't let you save it.

Comment: also most likely in real-life applications there would be 2 types of orders: draft orders and orders.

Comment: but you didn't explain why you would never recommend HATEOAS.

Comment: @konrad its a bit off topic. basically no client can be clever enough to understand HATEOAS.

Comment: @Ewan "basically no client can be clever enough to understand HATEOAS." how is that? It will be just more things to implement in the API client code, reading links and passing them in subsequent requests.

Comment: @konrad maybe ask a seperate question about HATEOAS its a bit involved to into in comments and im sure other people will have views on thr subject too

Comment: It's not a matter of HATEOAS. It's totally out of place in this question. You are asking which way is preferable for you to implement the operative "UPDATE" via REST (updating Items or updating the whole order). The only possible answer is **depends**. Check out your domain constraints and business rules and pick the one aligned to these premises. REST APIs are a mere extensión of a given domain. Your domain models real-world concerns and mechanics. Your REST API should "transpire" these rules and concerns. For the sake of the *consistency of the whole system"

Comment: Additionally, when you send back the resource to the server, you don't send the HATEOAS representation you got with *GET*. You may send a total different representation. For instance, you will never send back the "links" or "relations" since it's the server's responsibility to decide the links it wants you to discover and navigate through.

Comment: @Laiv yeah true.

Comment: is it good idea to make separate endpoints to update collection? like `AddOrderItemToOrder` `RemoveOrderItemFromOrder`

Comment: oh nvm it's the 2nd solution @ewan described.

Comment: they sent you links, you can send links back. eg callback url